# Staging failed in IBM Bluemix

Tags: php, database, ibm-cloud

I had deployed domjudge in IBM Bluemix. It has been working fine until the last 3 days. Today, I tried to change database connectivity in  `DOMJudge-Web/domjudge-4.0.5/lib/use_db.php` with clearDB. I have only changed the following lines in the previously mentioned file:

```
$priv = "dummy";
$host = "us-cdbr-iron-xxxx-xxx.cleardb.net";
$db   = "mydbname";
$user = "myusername";   
$pass = "mypassword";
```

The same lines are added into the `DOMJudge-Web/domjudge-4.0.5/lib/use_db.orig` file.

After building and deploying the app, it does not run. The app error log is furnished below:

> 1/1/2016 6:21:30 AM    OUT STG -----> Downloaded app package (26M)
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 4.1.5
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    OUT STG Installing HTTPD
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/scripts/compile.py", line 51, in
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG .from_build_pack('lib/additional_commands')
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 189, in extensions
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG process_extension(path, ctx, 'compile', process, args=[self])
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/utils.py", line 69, in process_extension
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG success(getattr(extn, to_call)(*args))
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/httpd/extension.py", line 43, in compile
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG .package('HTTPD')
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/builder.py", line 165, in package
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG self._installer.install_binary(key)
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/cloudfoundry.py", line 206, in install_binary
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG strip=strip)
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/cloudfoundry.py", line 176, in _install_binary_from_manifest
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG self._dwn.download(url, self._ctx['TMPDIR'])
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG File "/var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/aee11c73-6b49-4e76-8781-e4b28e25e848_6cbec4f53c789b674bc4f011895cfb0f72c4d3e0/lib/build_pack_utils/downloads.py", line 50, in download
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG raise RuntimeError("Could not download dependency: %s" % url)
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR STG RuntimeError: Could not download dependency: /httpd/2.4.12/httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    OUT STG Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
>
> 1/1/2016 6:21:31 AM    ERR API encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase

I cannot identify the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Which was the previous DB type bound to the application?

Comment: Previously i used InnoDB

Comment: What's confusing about the error message? The dependency is no longer available at the location your script is trying to find it. (It was probably a buggy version with a security flaw.) Why not alter your script so that it obtains 2.4.18 instead?

Comment: The issue is with the buildpack used. Please provide more details about it.